# Appending textarea.val to <p> in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I'm not an expert in JQUERY but I wanna append texts in a  into another section of the html, say,

. My code isn't working fine. Can I please have some guidance? Thanks in advance ^^

This is my HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
  <div id="main" class="box">
    <h2>Create story</h2>
    <textarea rows="30" cols="50"  ></textarea>
    <select>
      <option value="style1">Inconsolata</option>
      <option value="style2">Droid Sans</option>
      <option value="style3">Cutive Mono</option>        
    </select>
    <button id="change_font">Change font</button>
  </div>
  <div id='story' class="box">
  <h3>A short story</h3>
  <p></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and this below is my JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('textarea').change(function(){
    $("p").append('textarea'.val());
});
});
```

Can I know where I did wrong? please give me some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    $("p").text('');
    $("p").append($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('textarea').change(function(){
    $("p").append($(this).val());
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LgRpL/)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple:
just change the

```
$("p").append('textarea'.val());
```

to

```
$("p").append($(this).val());
```